# Laravel translatable won't let me get my original data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-translatable

I'm using a package called dimsav/laravel-translatable to provide translations for some columns in a table I have.
The table called Articles and has the following fields: ID, Title, Body, Picture, user_id and I'm using the package dimsav/laravel-translatable to create a translation for it. So then I created another table called Articles_Translations which contains ID, article_id, Title, Body. Both, the Title and the Body are translations of the original. Now when ever I try to get the data of the Article, I get instead its translations (the translated title, and the translated body) but the rest of the columns are fine. 
In my Article Model, when I delete the line :

```
use Translatable;
```

Everything goes back to normal, and I can get the original data and not the translated one.  But also when I delete this line, I can't access my translated fields. Has anyone ever faced a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was with the locales of the app. it was set to the default language of the translation. it can be changed in config/app.php